Какие библиотеки юнит-тестов сейчас популярны?
Поделитесь, пожалуйста, знаниями по следующим вопросам по тестированию:

Какие библиотеки юнит-тестов сейчас популярны?
Есть ли принципиальная разница для работодателей, какую библиотеку я использую для тестирования? Может ли быть отсутствие опыта использования какой-то конкретной библиотеки существенным минусом, или главное - сам навык написания тестов, а конкретная библотека вторична?
Уступает ли встроенная в VS библиотека MSTest другим актуальным библиотекам, или на данный момент разница несущественна?
Как очищать проект от мусора, который создают тесты, и нужно ли это делать?
Есть ли возможность писать тесты прямо внутри тестируемого класса, чтобы не создавать отдельно классы для тестов и лишние ссылки?

Заранее спасибо всем откликнувшимся!


xunit, nunit, mstest
Нет, на чем скажут, на том и придется писать
Что значит "мусор"? Если речь про всякие сайд-эффекты, то да.
Это очень плохо, не надо так делать. Разделяем суп и мух по разным тарелкам.


Спасибо за ответ! Под мусором я имел ввиду пространства имен не относящиеся непосредственно к программе и необходимые только для тестов, а также ссылки на проекты с тестами. По поводу написания тестов непосредственно внутри тестируемого класса - несколько странно слышать, что это нежелательно... В курсе, по которому я учусь, данная возможность библиотеки nUnit преподносилась как преимущество...

Тесты никто не пишет - поэтому без разницы какую библиотеку ты не будешь использовать

Интересно... Как же жить без тестов?..
